# Obscure C++ syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Comma Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

About a year ago I noted some obscure syntax in a coding project I was working on:

```
table_value = table_index += 2, valueFromTable(table_index);
```

Does anyone recognise this?, it's like an assignment with an additional statement. This compiled in our entire suite of cross-platform compilers, so I'm pretty certain its valid C++ but I've never seen anything like it.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Gearoid

EDIT: heres some working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int valueFromTable(int a) { return a ; }

int main()
{
  int table_index = 0 ;
  int table_value = table_index += 2, valueFromTable(12);
  cout<<table_value<<endl;
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Here is a fun interview question and answer: "What's wrong with int a[1]; a[1, 0] = -1;?" -> "The first index is out of bounds".

Comment: Wow, thanks for the feedback y'all, I suppose I should've just searched for "comma c++", as google points to the answer immediately.

Comment: litb, that's interesting but I'm confused. The -1 isn't actually assigned to the int at index 1 is it? So how can it be out of bounds?

Comment: @litb: why not make the question even more weird: `a[1,0] = (-1,-2)`

Comment: How about `(0,1)[a] = (1,0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).
It's standard C and C++ but heavily frowned upon.

It evaluates both arguments, and returns the result of the second.

Comment: Is this the same when used in `for` loops? `for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i, ++some_other)`  Just a qualification on the 'heavily frowned upon' part if so, ie. avoid when it's obfuscatory.

Comment: @Steve: "heavily frowned upon" doesn't mean "always a bad idea", it just means someone always thinks it's a bad idea. I call this the "passive-aggressive voice": "oh no, it's not *me* criticising *your* code. It's just that people don't like it, in general, when it happens". The kind of generalization that on Wikipedia attracts those little [Who?] tags ;-)